# ACCESS VBA - Double Entry in Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I enter new MAC USER, it created 2 entries in the table. No clue why. I have more field in the table, which are not addressed in the adding, and will later be added in the individual row of the table.

```
Private Sub cmd_AddMAC_Click()

'Create new MAC and Folder
Dim rstMAC As Recordset
Set rstMAC = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbl_2_MAC", dbOpenDynaset)

With rstMAC
.AddNew
!MAC = Me.txtMAC.Value
!Level4 = Me.txtLevel4.Value
!Level5 = Me.txtLevel5.Value
!PrimeOrganization = Me.txtPrimeSection.Value
!SubOrganization = Me.txtSubSection.Value
'Add Additonal Fields here - see above !NAME = Me.txtName.Value
.Update
.MoveLast 'move to the last record to get the newly created ID
Dim lngIDMainMAC As Long
lngIDMainMAC = !IDMainMAC ' get the value of the  newly created ID
End With

' Create new folder on drive
Dim strFolderPath As String
strFolderPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\MACs\" & Me.PrimeSection.Value & "," & Me.txtLevel5.Value & " (" & lngIDMainMAC & ")"

If Dir(strFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir strFolderPath
MsgBox "MAC Folder Created Successfully!"
Else
MsgBox "Folder already exists"
End If


'CleanUp
rstMAC.Close
Set rstMAC = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am just wondering, since the form is not closed if that is creating the double entry......but I do not know why it would do it. it worked prior without having the VBA and only entering data into the table. that also did not created the corresponding folder on the drive.......

Checking Form and created a brand new form. both come back with the same issue that it created 2 entries in table. I only receive one entry under C:.....MACs

Comment: do not use .MoveLast  after .Update . instead  to get last inserted id use this lastID = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)

Comment: You can get new record id without movelast or select identity.   With DAO
.AddNew  'new record gets Id
lngIDMainMAC = !IDMainMAC ' get the value of the  newly created Id

Comment: I will assume that you create one record via VBA. It is not reflected in the form until you perform refresh (F5). You create another record manually through the form, because you don't see (yet) a record created programmatically.

Comment: Why are you using code to create record? If form and its controls are BOUND, data input creates record in table. Then, if you use code to create a record in same table, two records are created.

Comment: Helpful hint:  1. ("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0) can you elbotsate that a bit more?

Comment: @June7  you are right. have them bound and in the form. I assumed I need to bound them to relay to the the table.

Comment: the code looks ok though grab id inside addnew.  when inserting records in this way avoid self reference problems by making sure no form controls from which you are getting values are bound to fields in Tbl_2_MAC.

Comment: @June7 is right. Remove the full code and the bound form will insert the single record for you.

Comment: @june7 your hint about creating code and having the field bound was golden. I deleted the fields an added them unbound and it worked